# copy-and-rename with TortoiseHg in Windows

Tags: tortoisehg

I am used to TortoiseSVN, and have just started working with TortoiseHg. While I like it much more, I am failing to find a good way to perform a very typical (for out way of working) procedure: copy and rename.

Use case: I create a file, develop it under version control. Then I would like to derive another file from this one. We work with Zemax optical models, therefore it often makes sense to have two files with almost the same contents. For example, the optical system is exactly the same, but one surface reflectivity is different.

With TortoiseSVN, I could do copy-and-rename. The new file would have the same content, but a different name. SVN would know, that it's not a brand new file, but a file derived from something SVN already knows. So the history would continue, and changes from the parent can be seen.

With Hg, a similar command would be `hg copy old_name new_name`. It does exactly what I  need. But how can I do the same with TortoiseHg?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to copy using TortoiseHg.

But you can copy manually, and use the same procedure used to detect renames.

1. Select the file in the Commit panel, bring the popup, then click **Detect renames...**
   [image: select the file]
2. Detect the copy, then click **Accept Selected Matches**:
   [image: detecting copy]
3. The file label will show when the file is a copy:
   [image: showing as copy]